# How do you add a widget to the side of a page

Tags: widgets

I have been to appearance and it will add it to the main Home page but I cannot add it to the right or left side of my page.

Comment: Hi, do you see a place to insert sidebar widgets or is there only one place for home page?

Comment: just on the homepage

Comment: Then you should register a widget before placing it. i will post an answer for you.

Comment: what exactly you are asking? you want to create a widget? or your widget is not appearing in the sidebar on your desired page?

Comment: the second one I am trying to put a widget on a page for example I have a page Volleyball with description on the right side I would like to add a widget that students can click on and get course description

Comment: what i understand is you already have a widget with your content in it now your widget is not appearing on your desired page like Volleyball you said. right?

Comment: yes correct When I activate the widget all the info is just posting to the main page in correct location

Answer (score 0):

To register a sidebar widget, head over to `Appearance > Editor` and select the `function.php` from the right side. Then copy and paste this code at the end of your `function.php` file.

```
function custom_register_widgets() {
    register_sidebar( array (
        'name'          => __( 'Sidebar widget'),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-custom',
        'description'   => __( 'Widgets dragged here will appear in the right sidebar.' ),
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
        'before_title'  => '<h5 class="widget-title"><span>',
        'after_title'   => '</span></h5>'
    ) );    
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'custom_register_widgets' );
```

Now you need to call your widget in order to display it. Again from the right side, select `sidebar.php` and paste this code in the place you need:

`<?php
        if(is_active_sidebar('sidebar-custom')){
        dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-custom');
}?>`

Comment: wow Mr Johansson your amazing let me go and see if it works! thank you again

Comment: You're welcome. check if you can see the additional widget in the widget panel after adding this to your code.

Comment: Ok I am new to this application so it may take me a bit to figure it all out. Thank you again I will try and if I cannot make it work I will come back and send you another ping :)